# How can i fix this method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I want someone help me to rewrite this method to make it able to find the matches while it can't

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)    {
      if (otherObject ==null)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         Contact otherContact = (Contact)otherObject;
         return (first.equals(otherContact.first) && 
               last.equals(otherContact.last)&&
               phone.equals(otherContact.phone)&&
               email.equals(otherContact.email));
      }    }
```

It shows me there is No matches while there are matches in my input

```
public void displayMatch()
{

    System.out.println("Enter keyword: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = input.next();

        for (Contact c : contacts)
        {
            if (in.equals(c)) {
                System.out.println(c);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No matches.");
            }
        }   
}
```

Comment: You are trying to compare a `String` against a `Contact` and this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Contant of arraylist with keyword

Comment: What does this "keyword" represent?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are comparing String with an Object, it wont work. you need to compare two objects.

so what you do is ask input from user, create `Contact` object and call equals. see below

```
    public void displayMatch() {

        System.out.println("Enter keyword: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        String phone = input.nextLine();
        String email = input.nextLine();

        Contact inputContact = new Contact(firstName, lastName, phone, email);


        for (Contact c : contacts) {
            if (c.equals(inputContact)) {
                System.out.println(c);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No matches.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should also be suggested that they implement the `@Override equals()` method and `@Override hashcode()` on their `Contact` class

Comment: @Draken Agree. whenever using Collection, equals and hashcode should always be overridden.